# child elements not loading using jstree

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jstree

i am new to jstree and trying to load a tree via JSON url. The child elemnts are present in another URL to access that url, the parent id needs to be appended to the basic url. I am getting the roots nodes but not the child elements.

```
<html>
  <head>    
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function () {
            var list=[];
           var list2=[];
           var genreId=6628;
           var state="";
             var name=[];
             var j=0;
           $("#geo").click(function(n){
         var url="my url";
              if (n){  
                            name[0]=0;
                             if(name[j] !="undefined"){  
                             //alert(n.attr("name"));  
                             genreId=name[j]; 
                             j++; 
                             } 
                             } 
                             url=url+genreId;   
                $.getJSON(url,function(data){
                   var docs= data.response.docs;
                   for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
                    var state= "closed";
                       list2.push({"data": docs[i].description ,"attr" : { "name" : docs[i].id },"state":state});
                      name[i]=docs[i].id;
                   }
            });
                $("#demo1").jstree({
                   "json_data" : {
                    "data" : list2
                }, 
                "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui" ]
          });      
       });
       });  
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="geo">get json</button>
        <div id="demo1"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle example? I am bit lost in your code.